# Django Rest API VIEWSET custom validation on post request

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm new to django rest framework.

Here is `model.py`

```
PRICE_CHOICES = (
    ('high','High'),
    ('medium', 'Medium'),
    ('low','Low'),
)
class Book(models.Model):
    price = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=255,choices=PRICE_CHOICES)
```

My api `views.py:`

```
class BookViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Book.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BookSerializer
```

and `serializer.py`:

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('id', 'price', 'status')
```

want to override price field.

Comment: what do you want to do with price field?

Comment: Just want to return if price is high

Comment: ok you want to show price if it is high else remove this field?

Comment: If price is high I want to alert him price is high

Answer (score 1):

You can throw an error when price exceeds a limit like this.

```
 class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = Book
            fields = ('id', 'price', 'status')

        def validate_price(self, data):
             if data > threshold:
                 raise ValidationError(message='...')
             return data
```

If you want to alert a user and based on his response you want to make a decision then you need other logic. You need to introduce a new check variable/param in post input.

To set one book for user per day override validate method in serializer

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = Book
            fields = ('id', 'price', 'status')

        def validate_price(self, data):
             if data > threshold:
                 raise ValidationError(message='...')
             return data
        def validate(self, data):
             # your logic, et user detail and date and check it with db. if found raise exception as shown above.
```

Comment: Thanks. If I want user can only one book in a single day How to implement this

Comment: The model is missing and I have only limited info. But I updated answer and it may help.

Comment: @a_k_v In your answer, if the price is higher than the threshold, the data will not be saved in DB. It needs to be clear what is the requirement here i.e. if we don't want to save higher price or do we want to save a higher price but with some kind of notification to the user. If the latter is the case, we can use signals with the post_save receiver.